# Splitting up JSON strings that are in arrays of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, json, string, swift

I have a function that uses Swifty JSON. It retrieves the data from my DataManager file, which grabs info from this JSON string http://www.kuakes.com/json/ 
My function in my tableViewController file breaks down the JSON into information I need like title, id, time, etc. My problem is that the title entry contains the location and the richter scale, and I need to break that up into two separate strings - one for scale, and one for location.
Like this entry: {"id":153355,"title":"mb 4.6 AZERBAIJAN","link":"http://www.emsc-csem.org/Earthquake/earthquake.php?id=443813","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":0,"west":0,"lat":40.799999,"lng":46.919998,"depth":10,"mag":4.6,"time":"2015-05-26 01:20:35 UTC","timestamp":1432603235}

Formatted:

```
{

    "id":153355,
    "title":"mb 4.6 AZERBAIJAN",
    "link":"http:\/\/www.emsc-csem.org\/Earthquake\/earthquake.php?id=443813",
    "source":"http:\/\/www.kuakes.com",
    "north":0,
    "west":0,
    "lat":40.799999,
    "lng":46.919998,
    "depth":10,
    "mag":4.6,
    "time":"2015-05-26 01:20:35 UTC",
    "timestamp":1432603235

}
```

"mb 4.6 AZERBAIJAN", <- I'd want 4.6 for scale, and Azerbaijan for location. 
I'm not sure how to do that, and this is what I tried:

```
func getEarthquakeInfo(completion: (results : NSArray?) ->Void ){


    DataManager.getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess {
        (data) -> Void in

        let json = JSON(data: data)


        if let JsonArray =  json.array {

            for appDict in JsonArray {
                var ids: String? = appDict["id"].stringValue
                var title: String? = appDict["title"].stringValue
                var time: String? = appDict["time"].stringValue
                var lattitude: String? = appDict["lat"].stringValue
                var longitude: String? = appDict["lng"].stringValue
                var information = AppModel(idEarth: ids, title: title, time: time, lat: lattitude, lng: longitude)
                var title2strings = title!.componentsSeparatedByString(" - ")
                var scale = title2strings[0]
                 var location = title2strings[1] // Error: Array index out of range
                println("\(scale)")
                self.info.append(information)
                completion(results: self.info)
            }


        }

    }

}
```

If I run the program without putting in location, it prints scale just fine. However, if some entries are not separated by a " - " between the scale and the location, it gives me the whole thing. Ex. M 3.1 Southern Greece I think that's probably why I'm getting an error at `var location = title2strings[1]`

If somebody could help me with this, I'd appreciate it.

Update: My ultimate goal is to get ALL the title entries separated into scale and location, even if some of them aren't separated by a "-". I can't leave out the ones that aren't separated. If anyone can suggest a way to do this, that'd help a lot.

Comment: First, format the JSON.  There are several sites on the web that will do this for you, and it's much easier to understand if you format it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out another way myself. I replaced all the title entries that had "  " with " - " using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString. After that, I was able to split up ALL the strings.

```
func getEarthquakeInfo(completion: (results : NSArray?) ->Void ){


    DataManager.getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess {
        (data) -> Void in

        let json = JSON(data: data)


        if var JsonArray =  json.array {
            JsonArray.removeAtIndex(0)

            for appDict in JsonArray {

                var ids: String? = appDict["id"].stringValue
                var title: String? = appDict["title"].stringValue
                var time: String? = appDict["time"].stringValue
                var lattitude: String? = appDict["lat"].stringValue
                var longitude: String? = appDict["lng"].stringValue
                let newString = title!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("  ", withString: " - ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                var title2strings = newString.componentsSeparatedByString(" - ")
                var scale = title2strings[0]
                var location = title2strings[1]
                var information = AppModel(idEarth: ids, title: title, time: time, lat: lattitude, lng: longitude, scale: scale, location: location)
                self.info.append(information)
                completion(results: self.info)


             }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the string formats are consistent in your JSON source, but if they are you can try something like this:

```
let quakes = ["mb 4.6 AZERBAIJAN", "M 3.1 Southern Greece", "M 4.8 - Norwegian Sea"]

let cset = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()

var results = [(String, String)]()

for quake in quakes {
    var comps = quake.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(cset)
    comps.removeAtIndex(0)
    if comps[1] == "-" {
        comps.removeAtIndex(1)
    }
    let scale = comps[0]
    comps.removeAtIndex(0)
    let loc = " ".join(comps)
    results.append((scale, loc))
}

println(results) // [(4.6, AZERBAIJAN), (3.1, Southern Greece), (4.8, Norwegian Sea)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if swift can't split the string in two you will not have a result in the position [1] as the operation returned just one string that is in the position [0], for example if the title was "test" was split int result you would have result[0] = test and result[1] = nil when you try to read result[1] you would have the out of bounds error.

```
var title2strings? = title!.componentsSeparatedByString(" - ")
if let scale = title2strings[0]{
    println(scale)
} else { println("No value from scale") }
if let location = title2strings[1]{
    println(location)
}  { println("No value from location") }
```

Remember that now scale and location are optionals, you will need to use ! for force it to unwrap (not safe) or use `if let` again before access it.

I hope that helped you, good luck!

Comment: I tried that but at `if let scale = title2strings[0]{` and at `if let location = title2strings[1]`  it gives me: Error: Bound value in a conditional must be of Optional type

Comment: Doing it that way will print only the locations that have a "-" between it and its scale. My goal is to somehow get even the entries that don't have a "-" between the scale and the location. I'm apologize that I wasn't specific in my question.

Comment: You should always get values in title2strings[0] even it wasn't separate with "-" in title2strings[1] you will get only if separate for "-"